# ClockKit - reload timeline when Health Kit data changes

Tags: healthkit, apple-watch-complication, clockkit

I'm writing a complication that relies on Health Kit data.

I want to be able to reload the timeline when a the store changes, but not sure what to hook in to to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a mix of using `HKObserverQuery` with background deliveries and Watch Kit's background tasks are the way to do this.

More info here:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/healthkit/hkobserverquery
https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkwatchconnectivityrefreshbackgroundtask